# Can't install mongodb dependencies for nodejs (windows)

Tags: windows, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get a mongo database running with nodejs but when I type 'npm install mongodb' into my command line, I am getting the following error:

```
    C:\Users\me>npm install mongodb
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.1.3
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.1.3
    npm WARN package.json bson@0.1.3 No README.md file found!

    > bson@0.1.3 install C:\Users\me\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson
    > node install.js

    CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the file specified.
    npm ERR! bson@0.1.3 install: `node install.js`
    npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node install.js"` failed with 127
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the bson@0.1.3 install script.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bson package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     node install.js
    npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls bson
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_m
    odules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mongodb"
    npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\me
    npm ERR! node -v v0.8.9
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.61
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\me\npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! not ok code 0

    C:\Users\me>
```

It seems that bson0.1.3 is the issue. Does anyone know I might go about resolving this? I am using 64bit Windows 7, nodejs version 0.8.9, npm version 1.1.61 and have mongodb version 2.2.0 currently installed.

Answer (score 2):

Administrator permission of your cmd is required for npm to invoke CreateProcessW.

Comment: I think this is it.  But to elaborate, to start cmd with admin rights do a search for cmd and right click on the icon, then 'run as admin' (or something similar).

Comment: this did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried today and it worked fine for me the exact version of node and npm.
Is there any info you can find in the `npm-debug.log` file?

Though note there is Issue created in the GitHub repository:
https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/issues/14

Comment: I looked in the log - one line says 'failed to exec install script.' I'm really scratching my head here - is there a possibility that I borked things up on my end? All I've done is installed nodejs from nodejs.org (tried it again today - now on version 0.8.10), downloaded mongodb and then extracted the folder to C:\, opened up the cmd and typed in npm install mongodb. Is this what you did as well?

Comment: I tried also specifying installing earlier versions of the dependencies , like mongodb 0.9.x and mongodb 1.0.x, but it's always bson (0.0.4 and 0.0.5 now) refusing to install.

Comment: uninstall mongodb both with -g (global) and without - making sure that bson is uninstalled (check `node list` and `node list -g`) - then try `node install monngodb` again

Comment: Yep I tried npm list and it's not listing mongodb (or rather, it's coming up as an unmet dependency). trying 'npm uninstall mongodb' is throwing me an error: 'Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Eddie\Desktop\programming1\uninstall'

Comment: it seams like you have npm installed incorrectly. Download the installer and apply it again

Comment: make sure node.exe is in your system path so npm can correctly call it.

Comment: Node is in my system path (C:\Program Files\nodejs\) - I'm allowed to type in commands such as node -v and npm -v without being in that directory.