# Fatal error when installing mongodb with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to install MongoDB with NodeJS. I am using latest versions for both.
When I am typing `npm install` I am receiving this error

> C:\Users\Doodlemeat.node-gyp\0.12.2\Release\node.lib : fatal error LNK1107: in
>   valid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x23EBC [C:\Users\Doodlemeat\Desktop\Chat
>   \node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modu
>   les\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584220/cant-install-mongodb-dependencies-for-nodejs-windows?rq=1

Comment: That questions is over 2 years old. I think this is something to do with the new version of NodeJS. I tried to open the CMD in Administrator mode. Do you also receive this error?

Comment: Possible. Have you looked at their github issues?